# Why does VBA Step Over cause an Overflow error when done on a line containing a Double?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, debugging, double

I was stepping through some Excel VBA code (on a Mac) doing some other debugging, and suddenly I hit an Overflow error.  I narrowed down the error by repeatedly doing Step Over until I got down to a single line "a = b" where a and b were both Double and stepping over this line always gave me an Overflow error.  This didn't make any sense.

I rebooted my Mac.  I updated the Mac OS. I updated my Office apps. I checked Stack Overflow extensively.  No luck.  No one seems to have reported this bug as simply as I will below.

```
Sub TestOverflowBug()
    Dim a As Double
    a = 300#
    MsgBox a
End Sub
```

In the above code, first try running it to prove to yourself you will see a simple message.

Next, try setting a breakpoint on the line "a = 300#", then run the routine, and when it stops at the breakpoint, try to Step Over to the next line.

I always get an Overflow error.  It seems that trying to Step Over any line which contains a Double causes an overflow error.

What is going on?

---

I updated the question to add the "#" and remove the parens on the MsgBox line as suggested.  Neither helped.

About the environment, I am running **Excel for Mac** version 16.33 (20011301) from an Office 365 subscription.

Still very interested in solving this.  Thanks!

Comment: I am not getting any overflow.  did you try to run the code from a brand new workbook without any others open?

Comment: The only problem with this code is the redundant parentheses around what should be `MsgBox a`. Do you have code that actually reproduces the problem? See [mcve]

Comment: Which version/build of Excel are you running?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in responding.  I wasn't debugging as much so not running into the problem, but I am again now.

Comment: `No one seems to have reported this bug` - well, the first google link for "excel for mac debugger error on double" is https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/bug-in-excel-vba-macdebug-mode-any-floating-point/c6986948-9806-4e56-ab0b-30eb89a158d6, and the second is https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/bug-in-excel-vba-debug-mode-any-floating-point-operation-gt/m-p/894730...